# reading json encoded multiple php arrays using ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have used json_encode to encode two php arrays and now i have to read through ajax. Could anyone please let me know how to read those arrays through ajax request.

For example: i have a php file file1.php which has

```
echo json_encode($array1);
echo json_encode($array2);
```

Another file in which i read as follows:

For reading single encoded array i am reading like this

```
new Ajax.Request("file1.php",
       {
         method:'get',
         asynchronous:false,
         parameters: ({id: stopID, contains: tempContain}),
          onSuccess:function(data){
                var result=data.responseJSON;

                var keys = Object.keys(result);
                var values = Object.values(result);

                for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                     infoString += keys[i]+":"+values[i];
                }               
  });
```

Comment: You'll have to post the contents of your php arrays. Also, are you doing this through vanilla JavaScript or are you using a library like jQuery?

Comment: actually, can you show us what you have so far?  did you successfully get the ajax to return the encoded json?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery, it will save you a lot of time ;) There are examples in this link:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    //called when complete
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //called when successful
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //called when there is an error
  }
});
```